# Node HTTP request not returning all data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having an issue downloading complete data from a website.  I am doing the following

```
request({url: 'http://somehost/somefile.txt'}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(response.headers);
        console.log(body.length)
    }
});
```

The length is 64,472 bytes when downloaded above.  Content-Length is 65,536.  The file is malformed.

If I use wget to obtain the file, the resulting length is 65,536 and is a proper file.

Any ideas how to get Node to duplicate the results of wget?  I tried changing the User-Agent to wget in case that was it.

Thanks!

Comment: please don't link to malware, I changed the url to a dummy one, as that is all that's needed for the question

Comment: Theat does not look like http.request() from http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback what library are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** `request` has had an `encoding` option for awhile now and it's easier to just use that instead of manually buffering. For binary data you can set `encoding: null` as mentioned in the [`request` readme](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/README.md) to get back a single `Buffer` instance containing the binary data instead of a (utf8) string. Any non-`null` `encoding` value will be passed directly to the internal `Buffer`'s [`.toString()` method](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end).

---

The problem is that the `request` module buffers response data as a utf8 string when you pass in a callback as the second argument. So for binary data (or for textual data in an encoding that node does not support out of the box), you need to buffer the data manually. For example:

```
request({url: 'http://somehost/somefile.txt'}).on('response', function(res) {
  // res === http.IncomingMessage object
  var buffer = [],
      bufsize = 0;
  response.on('data', function(data) {
    buffer.push(data);
    bufsize += data.length;
  }).on('end', function() {
    var body = Buffer.concat(buffer, bufsize);
    // body now contains the raw binary data
  });
});
```